# upgraded cassandra - cant see old data

Tags: cassandra-2.1

I upgraded from cassandra 2.0 to 2.2.

[idf@node1 python]$ nodetool status

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.0.60  137.2 KB   256          100.0%            062d5387-d755-4220-9687-d8a793283882  rack1

[idf@node1 python]$
```

I had to recreate the keyspace and table as they did not show up. Now when I try to insert into this keyspace/table (from golang) I get

```
[idf@node1 python]$ 01:16:23.460090 Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM
```

Not sure if I created the ks exactly the same way as before

```
[idf@node1 cassandra_stuff]$ more CreateKeyspace.cql 
CREATE KEYSPACE tickdata
  WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
[idf@node1 cassandra_stuff]$
```

Also, I cannot see the data that belonged to this ks/table before upgrade.

Comment: Did you upgrade to cassandra 2.1, and then upgrade your sstables? 2.2 can't read 2.0 sstables, so if you skipped that step, you messed up. http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeC_c.html

Comment: Oops. Yeah, I didn't take the intermediate step. This aspect of cassandra is poorly thought out..

Comment: So then how do I get rid of the old data and start anew without these problems?

Comment: Cassandra is a disaster. After yum update, my keyspaces get deleted. How the heck does anyone use this thing in production?